# rails- convert time to utc based on browser time zone and start_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have browser time zone in a cookie variable and date in start_date variable as string .
say cookie['browser_zone']="Asia/kolkata"
& start_date = "2017/12/31 03:00:00"
how can I convert above date to with this time zone to UTC time zone.

Comment: have you tried ruby strptime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: How to parse date-time string into a specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091959/rails-how-to-parse-date-time-string-into-a-specific-time-zone)

Answer (score 3):

Use `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` to parse the time into the correct time zone, then convert it to `UTC`

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Asia/Kolkata"].parse("2017/12/31 03:00:00").utc
=> 2017-12-30 21:30:00 UTC
```