# Rails Time Zone not Setting Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run some reports with a cron job that are Timezone specific. I've read that setting Time.zone is a bad idea since it alters the Time.zone for other requests on the same thread. My alternative was to use `in_time_zone` on a Time object but that is causing issues too. I'm trying to query records between a certain start and end time for a given time zone. However, when I use `strptime` and then call `in_time_zone` it completely alters the day in reference to UTC. I simply want the day in CST. Here is my code:

```
Time.strptime("06/26/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").beginning_of_day #this outputs the beginning of the day in UTC.

Time.strptime("06/26/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)").beginning_of_day #this outputs the 25th at 19:00 hours.
```

Here is the link I found that stated setting Time.zone outside of the `application.rb` wasn't thread safe.

https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/25/rails-do-not-set-time-zone-to-avoid-time-zone-issues/

Comment: Reading Thoughbot's [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones) cleared up a lot of Rails time zone issues for me.

Comment: When you say "this outputs the 25th at 19:00 hours", what are you doing to output it? In the console it's `Fri, 26 Jun 2020 00:00:00 CDT -05:00`.

Comment: From what I can see, this should solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15784181/8271939

Answer (score 0):

Those return objects of different classes. One is the built-in Ruby [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html), the other is Rails's [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html).

```
# Time
Time.strptime("06/26/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").beginning_of_day.class

# ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
Time.strptime("06/26/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)").beginning_of_day.class
```

They also both return midnight on June 26th, 2020, though in different formats (because they're different classes) and in different time zones.

```
Time.strptime("06/26/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").beginning_of_day
2020-06-26 00:00:00 -0700

Time.strptime("06/26/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)").beginning_of_day
Fri, 26 Jun 2020 00:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

While they are the same time on the local clock, they are different points in time. The first is June 26th, 2020 00:00:00 UTC. The second is June 25th, 2020 19:00:00 UTC.

When you say "*this outputs the 25th at 19:00 hours*" it is likely because something is converting it back to UTC when it displays the time. Without knowing the context, this could be one of several things. Reading [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones) will help.