# How to use strptime with timezone in ruby?

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

I thought I had understood the strptime and everything was fine. But for some timezones in Europe, I get a very weird behavior. Can someone explain me this?

```
[82] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime('2023-12-20 12:30 PM Europe/Berlin', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p %Z').in_time_zone('Europe/Berlin')
=> Wed, 20 Dec 2023 13:30:00.000000000 CET +01:00
```

It does work fine with other timezones, for instance:

```
[83] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime('2023-12-20 12:30 PM Central Time (US & Canada)', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p %Z').in_time_zone('Central Time (US & Canada)')
=> Wed, 20 Dec 2023 12:30:00.000000000 CST -06:00
```

From what I get strptime is ignoring the Berlin timezone in the first case, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you using `tzinfo`? Does your system have a timezone with that name in the local timezone database?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `%Z` officially supports, but it seems `Central` (or `CST`) correctly gets parsed, but `Europe/Berlin` is being ignored (whereas `CET` works).

Comment: Here's a more minimal example: `DateTime.strptime('36000 Europe/Berlin', '%s %Z')` (timezone ignored!), `DateTime.strptime('36000 Central', '%s %Z')` (timezone parsed!).

Comment: I just started using timezones now. To be honest I was using datetime from rails, I guess tzinfo is already used as standard. It does have a timezone with that name, because .in_time_zone throws an error in case it does not. It is like `strptime` is ignoring Europe/Berlin, while `in_time_zone` is not. Anyway, shouldn't strptime throw an exeption when an invalid timezone was used?

Comment: I also noticed the CET working, but Europe/Berlin or Berlin should be valid, this is what really bugs me.

Comment: As reference
`[26] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo('Berlin') => #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Berlin>`
`[27] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo('Europe/Berlin')=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Berlin>`

Comment: You should probably avoid using Rails time zone aliases like `"Berlin"` or `"Central Time (US & Canada)"` if you can.  See the section about Rails time zones at the bottom of [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Note in the question marked as duplicated, the best answer is not the one marked as the accepted answer, but rather this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31928049/634824